# Organising structurally very similar classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> A little background - these are classes I've written on top of an Entity Framework model that represents tables on Sql Server with the following names:
>
> - `Dictionary.Databases`, `Dictionary.Schemas`, `Dictionary.Tables`, `Dictionary.Columns`
> - `SysData.Databases`, `SysData.Schemas`, `SysData.Tables`, `SysData.Columns`
> - `Compare.Databases`, `Compare.Schemas`, `Compare.Tables`, `Compare.Columns`
>
> Each 'set' of tables (eg `*.Databases`) are *roughly* identical - all of them contain relevant primary key fields (eg all the `Schemas` tables contain `DatabaseID` and `SchemaID`).
>
> Tables in the `Dictionary` and `SysData` schemas contain metadata fields extracted from the `sys` tables (eg the `Columns` tables contain `ColumnName`, `ColumnType`, `IsNullable` etc).
>
> The tables in the `Dictionary` schema also contain additional common fields for custom user-entered data (`Description`, etc).

I've noticed that the code I've just written for 4 classes looks *very* similar, and I feel like I should be able to write them better and apply some structure. They don't *quite* fit anything I know how to do with interfaces, however:

```
// for brevity's sake, only listing the very simple functions
// in the controllers here, if anyone's wondering why I'm
// bothering writing these classes instead of just going straight
// to my Entity Framework model when I need to, since these are all
// one-line methods

public class DictionaryDatabaseController {
    private DictionaryContext context;

    public DictionaryDatabaseController() {
        this.context = new DictionaryContext();
        // other initialization
    }

    public DictionaryDatabase FindDatabase(params object[] primaryKey) {
        return this.context.Databases.Find(primaryKey);
    }

    public DbSet<DictionaryDatabase> GetDatabases() {
        return this.context.Databases;
    }

    // ... etc ...
}

// This class is really similar to the one above...
public class SysDataDatabaseController {
    // also has a private context, just a different type.
    // SysDataContext and DictionaryContext both extend DbContext
    private SysDataContext context;

    public SysDataDatabaseController() {
        this.context = new SysDataContext();
        // other initialization
    }

    // Identical method, different but related return type.
    // DictionaryDatabase and SysDataDatabase both implement IDatabase
    public SysDataDatabase FindDatabase(params object[] primaryKey) {
        return this.context.Databases.Find(primaryKey);
    }

    // again, basically the same, but returning a `DbSet` of
    // `SysDataDatabases` rather than `DictionaryDatabase`s
    public DbSet<SysDataDatabase> GetDatabases() {
        return this.context.Databases;
    }

    // ... etc ...
}

// another class called CompareDatabaseController. Same stuff inside,
// but with CompareContext and CompareDatabase
```

See the commonality? I feel like I should be able to define an interface called `IDatabaseController`, but the return type of each function & the type of the `context` private member is different.

The two `context`s are structurally related - they both extend an Entity Framework class called `DbContext`.

Similarly `DictionaryDatabase`, `SysDataDatabase` and `CompareDatabase` all implement an interface called `IDatabase`

You can't, however, define an interface like this and make those classes implement it:

```
interface IDatabaseController {
    IDatabase FindDatabase(params object[] primaryKey);
    DbSet<IDatabase> GetDatabases();
    // ... other common functions ...
}
```

As the return type must be identical to that defined in the interface (eg, `DictionaryDatabaseController.FindDatabase` would have to return `IDatabase` rather than `DictionaryDatabase`). But I feel like I should be able to do *something* like this, and can't figure out what. It feels like something that's probably been commonly encountered before. Maybe there's a design pattern for it.

Making me further convinced that I can and should restructure this, there are 3 other sets of classes for `Schemas`, `Tables`, and `Columns` (`DictionarySchemaController`, `SysDataSchemaController`, etc etc), which again all look suspiciously similar to the above.

Any suggestions on how to improve this?

---

One thing I forgot to note - all the `Context` classes provided by Entity Framework are again all very similar and also feel like can be put into some kind of structure:

```
public class DictionaryContext {
    public DbSet<DictionaryDatabase> Databases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DictionarySchema> Schemas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DictionaryTable> Tables { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DictionaryColumn> Columns { get; set; }
    // ... other stuff ...
}

public class SysDataContext {
    public DbSet<SysDataDatabase> Databases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SysDataSchema> Schemas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SysDataTable> Tables { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SysDataColumn> Columns { get; set; }
    // ... other stuff ...
}

public class CompareContext {
    public DbSet<CompareDatabase> Databases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompareSchema> Schemas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompareTable> Tables { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompareColumn> Columns { get; set; }
    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Wasn't sure if this was fully suitable for CodeReview, as the code definitely works as-is, but I'm asking for stuctural stuff rather than providing my own and asking for it to be reviewed. Happy to move it if it's a better fit on a different SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inject the `context` instead of "newing it up" in the constructor you should be able to solve this. An interface may not be entirely appropriate, but a generic base class would be.

```
public class DatabaseController<TDatabase, TContext> 
                                where TDatabase : IDatabase
                                where TContext : IContext 
{
    private TContext context;

    public DatabaseController(TContext context) 
    {
        this.context = context;
        // other initialization
    }

    public TDatabase FindDatabase(params object[] primaryKey)
    {
        return this.context.Databases.Find(primaryKey);
    }

    public DbSet<TDatabase> GetDatabases() 
    {
        return this.context.Databases;
    }

    // ... etc ...
}
```

Using a filter allows you to access the interface members. Of course, that means you'd have to go mucking around with the auto-generated EntityFramework classes making them all implement a common interface though. So, all in all, I'm not sure I'd recommend it. Boilerplate code is the price we pay for working with many frameworks.

Comment: How would `TContext` 'know' that it's a `DbContext` and has a `Databases` member? Completely forgot this problem when writing the question (I'll edit it in), but again a similar problem where all these `Context` classes have `Databases`, `Schemas`, `Tables` & `Columns` properties but are different types. I think the injection method might work there too?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but what if you use a filter on `TContext` that ensures it implements a specific interface that exposes those common members?

Comment: It's that 'specific interface' for the context that's the problem there haha. See my edit to the question - same property name, different types. Can't do it with an interface (I think)

Comment: I saw that and updated my answer.